# Horizontal scrollview jump up and down during Scrolling in swift

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

Horizontal `UIScrollView` with page control is working but during scrolling, to subsequent pages, the view jumps up and down.

Click [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19atceJ0LwsGqbNphMgEIDJ_KeDlZziph/view?usp=sharing) to view a screen recording of my problem. *(via Google Drive, no file download required.)*

**Here is my code:**

```
func setupSlideScrollView(slides: [Slide]) {

    slideScrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y:0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
    slideScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * CGFloat(slides.count), height: view.frame.height)


    for i in 0 ..< slides.count {
        slides[i].frame = CGRect(x: view.frame.width * CGFloat(i), y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: view.frame.height)
        slideScrollView.addSubview(slides[i])
    }
}


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageIndex = round(slideScrollView.contentOffset.x/view.frame.width)
    pageControl.currentPage = Int(pageIndex)

}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some code that you have attempted.

Comment: Give me 20 minutes. On my way home.

Comment: can you give your email. this website does not allow me to add the code file. I want to email you the project.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, we prefer to have it visible to everyone. Instead, copy all the code inside the file and paste it into your question (leaving out any unnecessary code that does not relate to your question).

Comment: I was able to edit the post to add the code. see above. I have also created a screen recording that I would like to share since this will be the best way to describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Under function scrollviewdidscroll I added these lines of code:

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
 if scrollView.contentOffset.y > 0 || scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
    scrollView.contentOffset.y = 0
 }
```